# UITableCell stays grayed out after deleting and creating new

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I created a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell.
On swipe I delete the last row using

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

I open a new ViewController to provide input for a new cell;
Even if I do a "deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath" a new cell is still grayed out (the same way it looks after swiping and the delete buttons shows up - just that it is not moved to the left and no delete button is shown). It only goes back to normal after swiping to delete but canceling it.

I tried several things like
tableView.editing = NO;
[tableView endEditing: YES];
tableView reloadData
tableView reloadInputViews, ...

This problem only happens since iOS 7.
What can I do to have a regular color when creating a new row after deleting all previous rows?

Full code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:FALSE];

        [_data removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

Comment: [table reloadData] do anything?

Comment: No, I tried reloadData, reloadInputViews, endEditing, editing = NO - without success.